# Simple HTML DOM keeps returning plaintext rather than outertext (HTML) in PHP

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I am using the [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to scrape a webpage. I trying to get the html of a td element it keeps bringing back the plaintext rather than the html. I have tried outertext and innertext and still no luck.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

    class JobPosting {
        var $Id;
        var $PostDate;
        var $RequistionNumber;
        var $Title;
        var $Company;
        var $City;
        var $State; 
        var $Description;
        var $Requirements;     
    }

    function GetJobPosting($id)
    {
        $html = file_get_html('https://rew31.ultipro.com/PAC1016/JobBoard/JobDetails.aspx?__ID=*6CF6029C92AD592E');

        $jobposting = new JobPosting;

        $jobposting->Id = $id;
        $jobposting->RequistionNumber = $html->find('#DataCell_Req_Code')[0]->plaintext;
        $jobposting->PostDate = $html->find('#DataCell_Req_PostDate')[0]->plaintext;
        $jobposting->Title = $html->find('#DataCell_Req_TitleFK')[0]->plaintext;
        $jobposting->Company = $html->find('#DataCell_Req_ReqUDF3FK')[0]->plaintext;
        $jobposting->City = $html->find('#DataCell_Req_City')[0]->plaintext;
        $jobposting->State = $html->find('#DataCell_Req_State')[0]->plaintext; 
        $jobposting->Description = $html->find('#DataCell_Req_Description')[0]->outertext;
        $jobposting->Requirements = $html->find('#DataCell_Req_Requirements')[0]->outertext;   

        return $jobposting;   
    }
?>
```

The main issue is that I want to be keep the text formatting within the span. Meaning it will have all of the correct breaks and spacing but it appears that the breaks are getting replaced with spaces.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot the opening tag.

Comment: @acoder I do have PHP tags around this in my code. Is that what you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call neither `plaintext` nor `outertext`, because those are functions to remove the HTML tags.

The DOM object has an implicit [__toString](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) method that returns the html, so you just need to return that object, or concatenate it to a string to force the conversion:

```
$html = str_get_html('<html><body><div id="hello">Hello!</div></body></html>');
echo $html->find('#hello')[0];
```

This outputs `<div id="hello">Hello!</div>` wich is what you want.